Geodesic Behavior in the Calvo-Oller Embedding of Multivariate Normal Distributions
The $\textbf{Calvo-Oller Embedding}$, introduced by Calvo and Oller, provides a novel way to study multivariate normal distributions by embedding their parameter space into the manifold of symmetric positive definite (SPD) matrices. Let me briefly summarize the construction:
Let $\Theta = M_{n \times 1}(\mathbb{R}) \times P_n(\mathbb{R})$ be the parameter space of multivariate normal distributions $N(\mu, \Sigma)$, where $\mu \in M_{n \times 1}(\mathbb{R})$ is the mean vector, and $\Sigma \in P_n(\mathbb{R})$ is the covariance matrix.
The embedding $f: \Theta \to P_{n+1}(\mathbb{R})$ is defined as:
$
f(\mu, \Sigma) = \begin{pmatrix} 
\Sigma + \mu \mu^\top & \mu \\
\mu^\top & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$
This embedding satisfies the following properties:

$f$ is a diffeomorphism from $\Theta$ onto its image $f(\Theta)$.
$f(\Theta)$ forms a submanifold of $P_{n+1}(\mathbb{R})$.
The Siegel metric on $P_{n+1}(\mathbb{R})$ induces the Fisher information metric on $\Theta$:
$$
ds^2 = \frac{1}{2} \text{tr} \{ (\Sigma^{-1} d\Sigma)^2 \} + d\mu' \Sigma^{-1} d\mu
$$
The map $f$ is isometric between $\Theta$ and $f(\Theta)$.
$f(\Theta)$ is a $\textbf{non-geodesic}$ submanifold of $P_{n+1}(\mathbb{R})$, except when the mean $\mu$ is fixed.

This embedding provides a deep connection between the parameter space of multivariate normals and the geometry of the SPD manifold. However, I am struggling with the following conceptual issue:

Since $f(\Theta)$ is $\textbf{non-geodesic}$, we cannot generally claim that computing geodesics in $$P_{n+1}(\mathbb{R})$$ will correspond to meaningful geodesics in the original space of multivariate normal distributions, even though the embedding is isometric.
Specifically, when the mean $\mu$ is fixed, $f(\Theta_{\mu_0})$, where $\Theta_{\mu_0} = \{ (\mu, \Sigma) \in \Theta : \mu = \mu_0 \}$, becomes a geodesic submanifold.

$$\textbf{My Questions}$$: What are the implications of the non-geodesic nature of this embedding when working with multivariate normal distributions? Does it mean that geodesic computations on $P_{n+1}(\mathbb{R})$ are limited in their application to problems involving both the mean and covariance matrix simultaneously?
Basically in simple way I want to ask that if we cannot compute the geodesic using this embedding then what is the main use of this embedding, what application where I can use?
Any insights, references, or clarifications on these issues would be greatly appreciated!
